# How to Prove That the Variables Come In Plus/Minus Pairs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Consider the numbers, $a_1, a_2, a_3 \cdots a_n$ for some arbitrary $n$.

Given that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^k = 0$ for every odd integer $k$, prove that all of the non-zero $a_i$ come in plus-minus pairs.

For example, we could have $a_1 = 2, a_2 = -2, a_3 = 4, a_4 = -4, a_5 = a_6 = \cdots = a_n = 0.$

I tested this out for various values of $n$ and it seems to work, however, I have no idea on how to actually prove this.

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- show it is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$
- show that you must have $\max_i(x_i)=-\min_i(x_i)$ if this is true for all odd $k$
- suppose there is a minimally sizes counterexample, and remove (one of) the maximum value(s) and (one of) the minimum value(s) to get a contradiction

Comment: does my proof that I wrote below work?

Comment: @sfs2007 I think not: I suspect you need to show $b_1=-b_n$  before you take them out

Comment: how would I do that? Could you please write out the proof? (or at least the outline)

Comment: @sfs2007  Something like if $\max_i(x_i)=c$ and $\min_i(x_i)=-d$, then if $c > d> 0$ and $k>\frac{\log(n)}{\log(c)-\log(d)}$ then you will find $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^k \gt c^k - nd^k > 0$ and a similar argument when $d > c >0$.  So you must have $c=d$

Comment: oh ok that makes sense. thank you.

Comment: wait @Henry, I was going through your proof in a bit more detail and I ca'nt seem to figure out how you get $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^k < c^k - nd^k$. What argument do you use to prove such a thing? I can't seem to figure that part out.

Comment: @sfs I am claiming for large enough odd $k$ you have $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^k \ge c^k - (n-1) d^k > c^k - n d^k > 0$.  I assume it is the first inequality you are questioning.  The sum of $a_i^k$ must be at least what it would be if you kept the maximum term as it is and set all of the others to the minimum.